# Where is the map pointer icon pointing?

Tags: ingress

It's not pointing to your walking direction or nearest portal, neither to north. But it's changing the direction and i can't figure where/why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean the red and white double-ended pointer in the top-left of the screen, directly below the section with your level and XP, then that is a compass pointer and certainly should be pointing North, either to your North or the map's North. If it's not then maybe you need to [calibrate your phone's compass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300837/compass-calibration).

Alternatively, if you mean the coloured triangular pointer (I think the colour depends on your faction) near the middle of the screen, then that should be showing your current (approximate) position, and it should be pointing in the direction that you're facing (again if it's not, then you may need [to calibrate your phone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9583998/154061)).

You can tap the compass symbol in the top-left of the screen to toggle between the map showing North-up (so the compass pointer in the top always points straight up and the triangular pointer near the middle turns to show which way you're facing), or tap again to have the map rotate as you turn round (this means the triangular pointer always points up, and the compass and map rotate as you turn around).

If you're moving, then the triangular pointer also has a trail of light grey copies of itself that show your movement trail, and give an approximation of the speed you're moving at by the distance between them.

Comment: Note that a compass does not work when close to other magnet(ized material)s. This includes the inside of many cars, as well as some bike frames (like mine, unfortunately).

Comment: @MatthiasUrlichs this is a problem but not that big as you might think. Most Android phones I had have an issue that they need calibration. You need to flip your phone on two axis (shorter and longer side) and then turn them around (180 degrees) and back -- that's the third axis. This should make your compass work better in most cases. Better meaning being wrong not more then 30 degrees.